# How deep is too deep for embedded documents? Designing a voting app with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I am designing my first MongoDB database (apologies if this is a simple question) for use in a voting application. The concept for the app is that users will be able to vote for their favorite song during the one contest per week, with each contest consisting of a set number of entries.

My thought so far is that each Entry will consist of an Artist and a Track. The Track could be pulled from the list of Tracks related to an Artist based on it being 'active', signified by an indicator variable. Votes will be stored in the Entry object, and each Entry object will belong to a Contest. Finally, each Contest will store X entries.

My question:

Would the Contest collection end up being too complicated or 'too embedded' if it contains, say, five Entries, each with their own Artist documents, each in turn with their own list of embedded Tracks? Like so.

```
{
    _id: 'contest12345',
    winner: '',
    active: 1,
    startdate: '01162020',
    enddate: '01172020',
    entry1: {
        _id: 'artist1track1',
        votes: 0,
        artist: {
             _id: 'artist1',
             name: 'Artist 1',
             wins: 0,
             active: 1,
             tracks: [
                 { _id: 'track12345', title: 'Title 1', link: "https://soundcloud.com/artist1/track1", active: 1}, 
                 { _id: 'track12346', title: 'Title 2', link: "https://soundcloud.com/artist1/track2", active: 0} 
             ]
        }
    }, 
    entry2: {
        _id: 'artist2track1',
        votes: 0, 
        artist: { ... }
    }, 
    entry3: { ... },
    entry4: { ... },
    entry5: { ... }   
}
```

I've done some research, found a few questions that are similar but not specific to my questions but am unsure of what is considered "too deep". I think I understand what this [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) states, but am still unsure of what is ideal with MongoDB.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: "too deep"  means no exceed [16MB per document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a technical point of view, the limit size of a document is 16MB, which is not often reached. And MongoDB can handle embedded documents until 100 level of nesting. So you'll be fine with your model. 5 levels (or more) is quite usual.

It is more complicated to tell you if your choices is a good option. Ans it is said in the documentation, choices of documents' structure is multi-factorial :

> The key challenge in data modeling is balancing the needs of the application, the performance characteristics of the database engine, and the data retrieval patterns. When designing data models, always consider the application usage of the data (i.e. queries, updates, and processing of the data) as well as the inherent structure of the data itself.

But what is good with MongoDB is that you can change your mind quite easily and adapt your models step by step while your creating your app.

MongoDB university has a good introduction course to data modeling if you want to have a deeper understanding : https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M320/about

Comment: Thank you @Abk - the beginning of your answer was what I was wondering about - what is usual? What is common? I had some trouble finding examples like mine. I appreciate your response and I will take a look into the MongoDB University.